# Find maximum amount of children any patient has

Tags: oracle

I have a table that looks like this in oracle:

```
C_ID    C_NAME  PID
340001  RONI    P340
340002  Kitty   P340
343001  RAKER   P343
343002  Danny   P343
343003  olka    P343
318001  Beans   P318
318002  jamma   P318
318003  leena   P318
520001  Perry   P520
520002  mash    P520
520003  kitty   P520
520004  omc     P520
640001  Glass   P640
640002  brad    P640
310001  BAKER   P310
550001  JONES   P550
550002  joze    P550
550003  brad    P550
```

how do I find the max # of PIDs from this list?

Comment: max # of PID means?

Comment: Can you explain how children are linked to parents in the DB?

Comment: Have you tried something ? you'll not do your homework

Comment: the PID that appears most often and how many times does it appear?

Comment: i have used this statement to count the PIDs but I don't know how to make it a subquery to show which PID appears most often:  select pid, count(c_id) from TABLE group by PID;

Comment: Please clarify that you need, it's not clear from the description. The best way to do it - give some examples of desired outcomes

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `rownum`. This is much simpler than using window functions since you need only the highest count.

```
 select pid , ct FROM
(
select pid, count(C_ID)  ct
from TABLE1 group by PID 
  ORDER by ct DESC
 ) where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by PID and count the rows. This number must be equal to the max count, which is selected from subqueries

```
 SELECT PID, COUNT(*) As NoOfChildren
 FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY PID
 HAVING COUNT(*) =
     (SELECT MAX(NoOfChildren) FROM
         (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoOfChildren
          FROM MyTable
          GROUP BY PID)
     )
```

The result is

```
PID     NOOFCHILDREN
P520    4
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64de5/1/0

Comment: thank you, this is great. If I had a MyTable2 that also contained PID and wanted to select another column, say name, how would I join the tables and have it print as Name, PID, NoOfChildren ?

Comment: `SELECT T1.PID, T2.Name ... FROM MyTable T1 INNER JOIN MyTable2 T2 ON T1.PID = T2.PID GROUP BY T1.PID ...`

Comment: This is the statement I have put together. Do you see any errors in the syntax?

                                                                                           
 SELECT table2.P_name, table1.PID, COUNT(*) As NoOfChildren
 FROM table1 inner join table2 on
 table1.pid = table2.pid
 GROUP BY table1.pid
 HAVING COUNT(*) =
     (SELECT MAX(NoOfChildren) FROM
         (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoOfChildren
          FROM table1
          GROUP BY PID)
     );

Comment: The star (*) is missing from `COUNT(*)` twice. Note: `COUNT(*)` counts every row. `COUNT(ColumnName)` counts every row where `ColumnName` is not null.

Comment: i included the * in count(*) but it didn't copy into the comment. How do I have the code be blocked in grey? I am also getting the error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression when I run this query as is.

Comment: The query in grey (in the comment ) is not complete. The missing parts are replaced by "...". Its purpouse is only to show the INNER JOIN.

Comment: ok. how do I insert the INNER JOIN into the original statement? I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You did it already in the query that you posted in your comment. It is basically the same query as the one in my answer with addition of the table join in the FROM-clause. In the "..." you were meant to insert the missing parts from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function row_number for this:

```
select * from (
    select pid, 
        count(*) as cnt, 
        row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as rn
    from your_table t
    group by pid
) t where rn = 1;
```

In case you want all the pid if multiple exists for max number of times, you can replace row_number with rank